# What advantage do lock-in amplifiers give over doing an FFT and looking at the frequency spectrum?

Tags: fft

I get that for real time processing it's faster to IQ demodulate and filter, but if real time constraints aren't a factor, for raw precision and accuracy, what do we get out of lock-in amplification? Can we not simply take the FFT and just look at the information at the exact bin(s) corresponding to our excitation frequency of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but mostly no.

If the source and the sampling happen to be stable over the amount of time it takes to collect a vector to be FFT'd, then yes, you could do that.  However, you'd lose any phase information.  At that point you're basically just using the FFT as a band-pass filter.

If you say "aha! but I shall be smart and *synchronize* my sampling to my source!" then congratulations -- you've reinvented the lock-in amplifier (albeit one that gives you information on harmonics, which may be useful).

Comment: Would the short-term Fourier transform or wavelet transform preserve time or phase information?

Comment: Yes, but unless the sampling is synchronized to the carrier, phase information will be lost there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!